# Decode bits in C

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to decode binary that was encoded (most significant byte first) with the following loop.

```
int ch; // Has a value of, for example, 97 (which evaluates to 'a' with putchar(ch))
for (int i = 0; i < CHAR_BIT; i++) {
  printf("%d", !!((ch << i) & 0x80));
}
```

So far I have tried:

```
unsigned int byte[CHAR_BIT]; // Filled elsewhere
unsigned char result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < CHAR_BIT; i++) {
  result |= (byte[i] == '1') << ((CHAR_BIT - 1) - i);
}
putchar(result);
```

But the output is wrong, it seems as if the characters were shifted the wrong amount. Assuming the first block of code is in a file called prog1 and the second is in prog2, the output of this shell command should be `abc` but it is `bb (literal back tick followed by bb).

```
echo "abc" | ./prog1 | ./prog2
```

Comment: When you say the 'output is wrong' can you specify what the input/output is and what you are expecting

Comment: @BenWainwright See my update

Comment: Did you write the code that encodes the char, or was that given to you?

Comment: You wrote that ch is an int. Shouldn't it be a char ?

Comment: @BenWainwright I wrote it but I know it is correct because I have verified the output.

Comment: Please can you include the code that declares `ch`

Comment: When assigning result, you mix operands with int type (due to integer promotion) and char type. Especially with the OR ( | ) operator, this may be a bad idea...

Comment: @BenWainwright `ch` is the argument of the function that contains the block of code. It's my understanding (I'm new to C) that you can treat a char like an int because they are the same thing internally.

Comment: @Tim While they are both integer types, they have different size. A char is most often promoted to an int in most expressions, which is a common cause for subtle bugs. As Laurent says, mixing signed types with bitwise operators is a bad idea, because you might get unexpected results or bugs. If you are new to C, it is best to do all bitwise operations on an unsigned type of known size, such as `uint32_t`. Doing so will also prevent implicit promotion, because uint32_t is never smaller than int in practice (but could be in theory).

Comment: @Lundin I think you are missing the fact that he has written two separate binaries that are piped into each other

Comment: Why don't you run `echo "abc" | ./prog1` and see whether it prints correct results? Then you'll know if the problem is with prog1 or prog2.

Comment: Running `echo "abc" | ./prog1` correctly outputs `01100001011000100110001100001010`

Comment: Just a comment, in case it wasn't obvious, the last eight bits '00001010' are the encoding of the newline as in "abc\n".

Comment: when asking a question about a runtime problem.  the question needs to include code that cleanly compiles.   In this case, the question is missing the source code for prog1 and prog2, not just a couple of unrelated snips

Comment: in OSs where 'true' is defined as other than 1, for instance 2 or 0xFFFFFFFF the `!!` will not work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

**prog1.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CHAR_BIT 8

void encode(int c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < CHAR_BIT; i++) {
        printf("%d", !!((c << i) & 0x80));
    }
}

int main() {
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        encode(c);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**prog2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CHAR_BIT 8

void decode(char *byte) {
    int c = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < CHAR_BIT; i++) {
        c |= (byte[i] == '1') << ((CHAR_BIT - 1) - i);
    }

    putchar(c);
}

int main() {
    char byte[CHAR_BIT + 1];

    while (scanf("%8s", byte) == 1) {
        decode(byte);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
> echo "abc" | ./prog1 
01100001011000100110001100001010
> echo "abc" | ./prog1 | ./prog2
abc
>
```

If the encode/decode logic is the same as yours, then this line is suspect:

```
unsigned int byte[CHAR_BIT]; // Filled elsewhere
```

and knowing what transpired elsewhere might help to explain what went wrong.